# ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter.create(serializer_object, include: '*,user.**').to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

```
ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter.create(serializer_object, include: '*,user.**').to_json
```

I understand the code but not getting the meaning of **'*,user.**'** .

Can any one explain this **'*,user.**'** ?

**Question 2**

I want to add **references** in the include, How can I do that?

Comment: Does this work?

Comment: Yes, it's working condition. That line taking too much time (like 27 sec.). I want to reduce to 2 sec. so that I'm asking for this question.

Comment: try including only the references you need.

Comment: Two seconds to render a serializer? Are you mad?

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev not getting. can you give me the syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/adapters.md

This

```
include: '*,user.**'
```

means "include all immediate references of current object and also all references (recursively) of its `user` property.

This looks not very efficient (User class tends to be a god object in every app). Try including only the references you actually need. Something like

```
include: 'user,owner,whatever'
# or 
include: [:user, :owner, :whatever]
```